# FCM collapse_key overrides all previous messages (with different key values)

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As far as i am aware of FCM to override my notificaiton on server if it is not deleivered(means device is offline), i can set maximum of 4 keys as stated here

> To mark a message as collapsible, include the collapse_key parameter
>   in the message payload. FCM allows a maximum of four different
>   collapse keys per device to be used by the app server at any given
>   time. In other words, the FCM connection server can simultaneously
>   store four different collapsible send-to-sync messages per device,
>   each with a different collapse key. If you exceed this number, FCM
>   only keeps four collapse keys, with no guarantees about which ones are
>   kept.

So i experimented with this code in POSTMAN,

```
 {
    "to":"egAhXXXXXXXXI-HDeLB0SgpK5AmJ8nda1B1TNZrIV-Rpl-1Fqt15UPvfSBdYUWGQoJqaMCz29RvRELdaNE-KaiQvOP-QbmmcWMKe5Y_P7lA38NFiIl2RQHaVh5JJCtv6IId-7kRG1K76o",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Body one",
    "title" : "Title",
    "icon" : "beintent",
    "sound": "getsintheway",
    "color":"#ff0000"

  },
  "collapse_key":"Key 1"
}
```

I sent four messages with two keys(two message with each collapse_key). But only got last message when device came online.

Anyone having idea why it is so? And what exactly the use of **collapse_key** as same thing I can do from **tag**?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you use four *different* collapse-keys or same?

Comment: @AL. Obviously different... "collapse_key":"Key 1", "collapse_key":"Key 2" like that. And what about my second question "And what exactly the use of collapse_key as same thing I can do from tag?"

Comment: I believe the difference is that when the device is online the collapse key won't overwrite the latest message but tag will always overwrite. When it is offline->online they will behave the same.